# Conditionals & Control Flow in Python: Function should not take any arguments

Tags: python, function, arguments, return-value, conditional-statements

I am doing Python on CodeCademy.com once more, trying to make the function the_flying_circus() return true. Here are the instructions:

> Write an *if* statement in *the_flying_circus*. It must include:
>   - If , elif and else statements
>   - At least one of and, or, or not
>   - A comparator
>   - Finally, the_flying_circus() must return *True* when evaluated.

```
def the_flying_circus(evaluated):
    if evaluated == 1: 
        return True 

    elif evaluated == 0: 
        return not True or True

    else:
        return -1

print the_flying_circus(1)
```

Upon running this code, I get an output of "None" and I recieve the following error message from CodeCademy:

> Oops, try again. the_flying_circus should not take any arguments.

I don't understand what they mean. What arguments are they talking about, and how can I make sure they don't take any without disturbing the program?

Comment: Your function takes an argument, `evaluated`. The exercise tells you that the call `the_flying_circus()` (no arguments!) should return true.

Comment: *when evaluated* just means, *when the code is run*, not that there is a parameter named *evaluated*.

Comment: Also see http://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/552169be51b8878b110002d4

Answer (score 1):

Your function takes an argument:

```
def the_flying_circus(evaluated):
```

but the exercise asks you to create a function with no parameters:

> `the_flying_circus()` must return `True` when evaluated.

In that sentence, *when evaluated* just means *when the expression `the_flying_circus()` is executed*.

Your function just needs to meet the requirements; use the statements and operators, and make sure the function always returns `True`.

The following should pass:

```
def the_flying_circus():
    evaluated = 1

    if evaluated == 1: 
        return True 

    elif evaluated == 0: 
        return not True or True

    else:
        return not False

print the_flying_circus()
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Martjin Pieters, part of the problem is that your function takes an argument whereas you are explicitly told that it must not.

There is another problem, which is that your function will not necessarily return `True`.  Something like:

```
def the_flying_circus():
    if 1 > 0 and not 0:
        pass
    elif 2 > 3:
        pass
    else:
        pass
    return True
```

is a minimal (and thoroughly useless) working example.

Answer (score -2):

```
def the_flying_circus():
    if 2 ** 3 == 8 and 5 + 1 == 6 :
      return True  # Start coding here!

    elif the_flying_circus(2):
      return not True

    print the_flying_circus()
```

Comment: Hi Nolber, please format your answer. All code should be formatted as code and please add some explanation. I only see code :-/.